# cython tutorial 'using c libraries' is confusing

Tags: cython

https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/clibraries.html
is a rather confusing tutorial. Its first sentence says 'Apart from writing fast code, one of the main use cases of Cython is to call external C libraries from Python code.'
But its second paragraph says '......, the values are actually coming from C code,......'
So as a Python programmer, I am thinking to create a queue, feed the queue, pop from queue, etc., all within the Python. Why the data actually comes from C?

In the subsection `Mapping functionality`, it is mentioned again: "Also, since we already know that all values will be coming from C, it’s best to provide only cdef methods for now, and to give them a straight C interface." On top of the data originality issue, it is also confusing why we give them a C interface in the Python wrap?

In the same subsection, it also mentions "This becomes handy when reading values from a C array, for example." Would an actual example serve the purpose better?

In the subsection `Testing the result`, the example `test_queue.py` clearly feeds the queue with Python data!

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to accomplish... What is it that you actually want to do? Why do you think you need to use Cython for that?

Comment: I think you should read "......, the values are actually coming from C code,......" as "the values are coming from your Cython code, which has actually been translated to C".

Comment: I kind of see why it's confusing though: the `cdef` functions are more used as a Cython interface than a C interface (but are not callable from Python). I think a lot of the time when the tutorial says C it means "Cython (which is compiled to C)"

Comment: @DavidW, your explain makes sense, and the `cdef` is definitely misleading in this tutorial on wrapping C library since one cannot call `cdef` functions from Python. Later in the tutorial, the author changed from `cdef` to `cpdef`.